# how to plot high and low of during certain duration in tradingview?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I want to plot high and low between 10:00 am to 10:12 am in a 1 min timeframe. how to plot a horizontal line for this case?

```
//@version=5
indicator("High and Low Plotter", overlay=true)

// Input parameters
startHour = input(10, title="Start Hour")
startMinute = input(00, title="Start Minute")
endHour = input(10, title="End Hour")
endMinute = input(12, title="End Minute")

// Variables
var float sessionHigh = na
var float sessionLow = na

// Conditions
inSession = (hour == startHour and minute >= startMinute) and 
(hour == endHour and minute <= endMinute)

// Logic
if (inSession)
 if(high > sessionHigh or na(sessionHigh))
    sessionHigh := high
 if(low < sessionLow or na(sessionLow))
    sessionLow := low

 // Plotting
 plot(inSession ? sessionHigh : na, color=color.red, 
 title="High in Session")
 plot(inSession ? sessionLow : na, color=color.green, 
 title="Low in Session")
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Yes, please check question again

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `line.new` function. Something like this

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
sessionTime = input.session('1000-1012', 'Session')
tz = 'UTC-8'

session = time(timeframe.period, sessionTime, tz)
startSession = not na(session) and na(session[1])
endSession  = na(session) and not na(session[1])

var sessionHighPrice = 0.0
var sessionLowPrice  = 0.0
var firstBar = bar_index
line hLine = na
line lLine = na

if startSession
    hLine.delete(), lLine.delete()
    sessionHighPrice := high
    sessionLowPrice  := low
    firstBar := bar_index

if not na(session)
    if high > sessionHighPrice
        sessionHighPrice := high
    if low < sessionLowPrice
        sessionLowPrice := low

if barstate.islast
    hLine := line.new(firstBar, sessionHighPrice, bar_index, sessionHighPrice, extend = extend.right)
    lLine := line.new(firstBar, sessionLowPrice, bar_index, sessionLowPrice, extend = extend.right)
```